# MVVM Light 5 - Navigation Service passing wrong parameter

Tags: mvvm-light

I have upgraded to MVVM Light 5 and I changed my navigation methods from:

Messenger.Default.Send(new NavigateToPageMessage() { PageName = "UserDetailsPage", Parameter = id });

To the following:

_navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.UserDetailsPageKey, id);

The parameter I am passing does not seem to make it's way to the OnNavigatedTo event of the view anymore, the parameter is completely different, am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

This new method seems to give me the parameter I need: 
GlobalNavigation.GetAndRemoveParameter(NavigationContext)

Although now, when the app is tombstoned, I lose that parameter entirely. Before, when the app was restored I would still have that parameter in the NavigatedTo args, this allowed me to re-hit the server with that ID and get fresh data. Why have I lost this capability

Comment: What do you mean that incoming parameter is different? How did you configure your navigation service? You should give more details.

Comment: Edited my question above

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views.NavigationService navigationService = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views.NavigationService();
   var param = navigationService.GetAndRemoveParameter(this.NavigationContext);
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```